# How to call ora_hash function inside control file in sql loader?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to call a function(ORA_HASH) inside sqlldr but I'm not able to achive the target.

Data File

```
abc.txt
AKY,90035,"G","DP",20150121,"",0,,,,,,"","E8BD4346-A174-468B-ABC2-1586B81A8267",1,17934,5099627512855,"TEST of CLOROM","",14.00,"",14.00,17934,5099627512855,"TEST of CLOROM",14.00,"ONE TO BE T ONE",344,0,"98027f93-4f1a-44b2-b609-7ffbb041a375",,,AKY8035,"Taken Test","L-20 Shiv Lok"
AKY,8035,"D","DP",20150121,"",0,,,,,,"","E8BD4346-A174-468B-ABC2-1586B81A8267",2,17162,5099627885843,"CEN TESt","",15.00,"",250.00,17162,5099627885843,"CEN TESt",15.00,"ONE TDAILY",3659,0,"09615cc8-77c9-4781-b51f-d44ec85bbe54",,,LLY8035,"Taken Test","L-20 Shiv Lok"
```

Control file

```
cnt_file.ctl
    load data
    into table Table_XYZ
    fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
    F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21,F22,F23,F24,F25,F26,F27,F28,F29,F30,F31 ORA_HASH(CONCAT(F2,F5,F6,F9,F10,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F19,F21,F22)),F32 ORA_HASH(CONCAT(f23,H24,F7,F8,F3)),F33,F34,F35

sqlldr "xxxxx/yyyyy" control=cnt_file.ctl data=abc.txt
```

whenever I'm executing sqlldr from Linux box I'm getting below error

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 4.
Expecting "," or ")", found "ORA_HASH".
F29,F30,F31,KEY_CLMNS_HASH ORA_HASH(CONCAT( F2,F5
                       ^
```

Any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong. The immediate error is because the Oracle function call has to be enclosed in double quotes:

```
...,F31 "ORA_HASH(CONCAT(F2,F5,F6,...))",...
```

The second issue is that the concat function only takes two arguments, so you would either have to nest (lots of) concat calls, or more readably use the concatenation operator instead:

```
...,F31 "ORA_HASH(F2||F5||F6||...)",...
```

And finally you need to prefix the field names inside your function call with a colon:

```
...,F31 "ORA_HASH(:F2||:F5||:F6||...)",...
```

This is explained [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226):

> The following requirements and restrictions apply when you are using SQL strings:
>
> - ...
> - The SQL string must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

And

> To refer to fields in the record, precede the field name with a colon (:). Field values from the current record are substituted. A field name preceded by a colon (:) in a SQL string is also referred to as a bind variable. Note that bind variables enclosed in single quotation marks are treated as text literals, not as bind variables.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a virtual column on the table to which you are loading the data.

For columns which are deterministically based on other column values in the same row, that usually ends up being a more simple solution than anything involving SQL*Loader.